# 404: NOT FOUND Vercel

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, vercel

I depolyed a simple django app on vercel with github. The build was successful, but the site says 404: NOT FOUND

I edited `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in my `settings.py`

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['vercel.app']`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying a Django app to Vercel involves a lot of configuration. Since Vercel doesn't have a build config for Django, you would have to do that yourself.

### create a `vercel.json` file, then put this

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "project_name/wsgi.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config": {
                "maxLambdaSize": "15mb",
                "runtime": "python3.9"
            }
        },
        {
            "src": "build.sh",
            "use":"@vercel/static-build",
            "config":{
                "distDir": "staticfiles"
            }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src":"/static/(.*)",
            "dest":"/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "project_name/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

vercel.json serves as a configuration file for your Django application. It defines the Python version, the app's max size, and where to find static files.

### create `build.sh` for the build commands

```
#!/bin/bash

# Update pip
echo "Updating pip..."
python3.9 pip install -U pip

# Install dependencies

echo "Installing project dependencies..."
python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make migrations
echo "Making migrations..."
python3.9 manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python3.9 manage.py migrate --noinput

# Collect staticfiles
echo "Collect static..."
python3.9 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear

echo "Build process completed!"
```

The `build.sh` updates the current version of pip installed in vercel, installs your application's dependencies, makes migrations to your database, and then collects static files.

### In `wsgi.py` add

```
app = application
```

### In `settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".vercel.app"]
...
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles" / "static"
```

Deploy your app again when this configurations have been saved